# Show that the closures in the topology weak and the norm are coincide:

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y \subset  X$a vector subspace. Let $Y_f$ and $Y_F$ are the closures of $Y$ in the topology weak and the norm, respectively. Prove that $Y_F = Y_f$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x$ is not in $Y_F$, there is a member $f^*\in X^*$ such that $f^*(x)=1$ and $f(Y_F)=\{0\}$. The weak nhood of $x$ determined by $f^*$ and $\epsilon=1/2$ contains $x$ and is disjoint from $Y_F$. It follows that $x$ is not in $Y_f$. So the weak closure of $Y$ is contained in the norm closure of $Y$.

The reverse inclusion is obvious.

Comment: I believe it should be disjoint from $Y$ to imply that $x$ cannot be in the weak closure of $Y$.

Answer (score 4):

Each convex subset E of locally convex space X has equal closures in original and weak topologies. See theorem 3.12 in Rudin's Functional analysis.

Comment: Sometimes this is known as *Mazur's theorem*.